# O que é o JBOSS?

Tags: java, java-ee, jboss, ejb

Estou lendo um livro sobre  Aplicações distribuídas e  ele de vez em quando faz referências ao JBoss. Gostaria de saber em que ele consiste e qual a sua utilidade?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JBoss é um servidor de aplicação, que dá suporte e possui implementações da JEE(Java Enterprise Edition) e é homologado pela Oracle.
Um exemplo é implementação do JBoss de uma especificação JEE é o Weld, que é uma implementação do CDI.

Tomcat x JBoss: 
Muita gente pensa que não existe diferença entre os dois, mais há sim. O Tomcat é um container de servlets. Ele cobre parte da especificação Java EE com tecnologias como servlet e JSP, e tecnologias de apoio relacionadas como Realms e segurança, JNDI Resources e JDBC DataSources.

Já o JBoss cobre grande parte, como JMS, EJB, JAAS, JTA, JSP, JSF, Servlets e outros. Além de ter vários outros recursos.

Wildfly: A partir da versão 8.0.0 o JBoss virou Wildfly, além da troca de nomes teve várias melhorias e mudanças como a troca do container que era o JBossWeb para o Undertow.

Answer (score 5):

JBoss é um servidor de aplicação que implementa toda a especificação Java EE.

Isto é, dá suporte às implementações de JSF, JPA, EJB, etc. 
além das implementações, dá suporte a transações e segurança nas suas aplicações, tornando de certa forma transparente o desenvolvimento de componentes.

Conforme mencionado já acima, à partir da versão 8 o JBoss passou a se chamar Wildfly.

Como alternativa open-source ao JBoss, temos o Glassfish, que é a implementação de referência de toda a especificação Java EE.

E também como conforme mencionado, o Tomcat cobre apenas parte da especificação Java EE (Servlets, JSP, JNDI).

Answer (score 1):

É um servidor de aplicação para projetos Java, é utilizado em servidores e também para desenvolvimento.

Além do JBoss existe vários servidores de aplicações como: **Tomcat**, **Apache**, **IIS** (Microsoft), etc.